# Refreshing reference data

Tags: data

I have two objects. One that is an object that holds detail information. Then another object that holds information used form reporting. So I create a reference fiend to the configuration object say, RefObj__c. Then I create formula fields to get the data in the reference object by using RefObj__r.Name, RefObj__r.Value. I've noticed that if the Name and Value fields in the referenced instance change, the change is not reflected in the object that holds a reference, so I thought, to that instance. I was assuming that the RefObj__r.Name and RefObj.Value fields would be resolved at run time. How would I get the values to change when the referenced instance's data changes?

Comment: Formula fields are calculated on read of the data. Could you show some code and related debug output to illustrate the problem which you are experiencing?

Comment: There isn't Apex code associated. It is a simple formula like in the original question. I have a reference field that holds the reference to an instance in another object. Say for fun the reference field is named Ref__c that points to object Xobj__c. Then in Xobj__c there are fields Name, Field1__c, Field2__c, and so on. Then in formula fields, I use Ref__r.Name, Ref__r.Field1__c, etc. to map the values. I'd assumed that they were just reference pointers rather than true buckets that held the data once the reference was resolved.

Comment: It sounds like I'll have to write trigger that refreshes the values when an instance of the Ref__c object changes.

Comment: Formula fields are never out of sync. When a formula field is read by query or displayed on screen, the value retrieved is as of that point in time. Nothing needs to, or can be 'refreshed' when using a formula field. Can you show how you have noticed the formula fields behaving differently than this, possibly via screen grab images of the formula field definition and then the subsequent misbehavior that you experience?

Comment: I beg to differ. I have this kind of relationship set up. Then I had a job make the assignment between the Object1 and the reference object. I ran a report to show the values and noticed that one of the values in my reference object was not correct. I made the adjustments and then re ran the report. The old value was still displayed. Then I used the Developer Console to run a query to seen the values and I saw the old values. The data in Object1 did not reflect the changes I made in the referenced object. Thus why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Never mind. It works as described. I found another issue with data. Be careful when using someone else's data when comparing data in the sandbox. Funny how a simple little blank space can ruin your whole day.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. It works as described. I found another issue with data. Be careful when using someone else's data when comparing data in the sandbox. Funny how a simple little blank space can ruin your whole day.

Mark was right. The referenced fields are resolved at run time and I had an issue with data that I didn't suspect.